# 3.0+ grease pencil sampling problem

Tags: grease-pencil

i draw with grease pencil alot, but i've been sticking to 2.83 cuz in 3.0+ versions the grease pencil seems to sample alot less of the motion. this is very apparent when i'm tryign to draw really fast (like for storyboarding)

[image: comparison 2.83 vs 3.5, page of circles, some circles are turned into straight lines]

Comment: I cannot see the problem in the image. Could you explain what is supposed to be visible there?  I also fail to replicate any issues with sampling motion when drawing as fast as I can with version 3.5.1 and Wacom Intous tablet on Windows. It really captures all the motion and detail I can perceive. Are you sure it's not hardware performance issue?

Comment: the problem in post 3.0 for me is the sampling feels really jagged, when i draw a circle i get a semi-circle sometimes (with a straight line for when i do an arc). it could be a hardware issue as i just have a not-so-powerful laptop, but this was way less of a problem with 2.8 and 2.9 on my computer. :-\  

you have any idea what settings i should change? thanks so much for the response i really would like to use 3.5. if there's someway to increase the input sample rate that'd be cool. i'm trying on both my huion screen tablet and wacom bamboo both have same issues.

Comment: Might be a bug. You could try reporting it.